# Cannot create an empty vector and append new elements in R

Tags: r

I am just beginning to learn R and am having an issue that is leaving me fairly confused. My goal is to create an empty vector and append elements to it. Seems easy enough, but solutions that I have seen on stackoverflow don't seem to be working.

To wit,

```
>     a <- numeric()
>     append(a,1)
[1] 1
>     a
numeric(0)
```

I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong. Anyone want to help a newbie?

Comment: You could have done `a <- append(a,1)` as well, but `c()` would possibly be more idiomatic. And for a beginner, I should probably also mention that growing objects like this is ok when you're just learning and getting a feel of the language, but is considered bad practice (it will get very, very slow), and in general you should avoid it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`append` does something that is somewhat different from what you are thinking.  See `?append`.

In particular, note that `append` does not modify its argument.  It returns the result.

You want the function `c`:

```
> a <- numeric()
> a <- c(a, 1)
> a
[1] 1
```

Comment: @user1935935 Note:  `a <- c(a, 1)` assigns the value back to a.

Comment: @user1935935 Remember, R is a functional programming language: functions don't (usually) have side-effects. If you want to modify any object, you always have to "catch" the result via an assignment.

Answer (score 5):

Your `a` vector is not being passed by reference, so when it is modified you have to store it back into `a`. You cannot access `a` and expect it to be updated.

You just need to assign the return value to your vector, just as Matt did:

```
> a <- numeric()
> a <- append(a, 1)
> a
[1] 1
```

Matt is right that `c()` is preferable (fewer keystrokes and more versatile) though your use of `append()` is fine.